# single entry SQL/python

Tags: python, sql

im trying to do a blog post simple app in witch you can write and than edit or delete a post. 
I got so far that i can show post but i can not edit them

i did a /edit.html page on witch i would like to have a single blog post and than edit it. The problem is that the post does not appear

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import yaml
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap

app=Flask(__name__)
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)

db = yaml.load(open('db.yaml'))
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = db['mysql_host']
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = db['mysql_user']
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = db['mysql_password']
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = db['mysql_db']
mysql = MySQL(app)



@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = request.form
        user_name = form['user_name']
        besedilo = form['besedilo']
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO post(user_name, besedilo) VALUES(%s, %s)", (user_name, besedilo))
        mysql.connection.commit()
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/post/')
def post():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    result_value = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM post")
    if result_value > 0:
        posts = cur.fetchall()
        return render_template('post.html',posts = posts)


@app.route('/edit/<int:id>/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def edit(id):
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    result_value = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM post WHERE post_id = {}".format(id))
    if result_value > 0:
        post = cur.fetchone()
    return render_template('edit.html', post = post)

## here i would like to single out one entry and show it on

@app.route('/delete/')
def delete():
    return render_template('delete.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

edit.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block sub_content %}

<h1>{{post['user_name']}}</h1>
<h1>{{post['besedilo']}}</h1>
 {% if posts %}
   {% for post in posts %}
    <h3> <a href="/edit/{{edit['edit_id']}}">{{edit['title']}}</a></h3>
   {%endfor%}
{% endblock %}
```

### this should show single entry

Answer (score 0):

You may need to pass a properly prepared sql query not dynamic.
Try modifying your view like:

```
@app.route('/edit/<int:id>/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def edit(id):
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    query = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE post_id = {}".format(id)
    result_value = cur.execute(query)
    if result_value > 0:
        post = cur.fetchone()
    return render_template('edit.html', post = post)
```

Alternatively;

```
result_value = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM post WHERE post_id = %s", (id,))
```